# Facebook login not working with Amazon ELB with HTTP listener

Tags: amazon-ec2, facebook-php-sdk, amazon-elb

Before my site was in EC2 instance and it was working, today i have created another ec2 instance and added both to a ELB. After this facebook login is not working, it show the error "**Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request**"

Note : I have already Enabled load balancer generated cookie stickiness

Comment: Is this load balancing switching between different public URLs/domains? As the error message says, you need to use the _exact_ same redirect_uri value in the login dialog call, and in your request to exchange the code for a token afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe same domain with multiple ec2 instance, i have checked the redirect_uri and everything.

Note: Its working fine with TCP Listener and this error occurs with HTTP listener

Comment: _“Its working fine with TCP Listener and this error occurs with HTTP listener”_ - I have no clue what that is even supposed to mean here, and what it has to do with the Facebook login. _“i have checked the redirect_uri and everything”_ - what have you checked it _for_? The PHP SDK automatically creates the redirect_uri value based on the current script URL, unless you specify it explicitly. So if you know what value is used when the login dialog is called, you could explicitly specify that same URL in your code part where the code is exchanged for a token.

Comment: @CBroe In ELB settings there is an option for protocol settings thats called listeners.

The problem is while getting the token from code, i have checked my redirect_uri and the returning uri from Facebook its same.

Comment: _“i have checked my redirect_uri”_ - have you checked it in _both_ relevant places, and made sure the value is exactly the same?

Comment: @CBroe The two uri are same (except the callback from fb it have a code and state parameter)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151380/discussion-between-samnad-sainulabdeen-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
```

This line of code not working with the ELB HTTP listener, so i am using the below line of code to get the Access Token from Facebook.

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/oauth/access_token?client_id={app_id}&redirect_uri={your_redirect_uri}&client_secret={app_secret}&code={code_parameter}');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need either share cookies between nodes (e.g. via mysql) or enable sticky session at ELB.